# I cannot figure out how to Rig Eyes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, node-editor, transparency, rigidbody

So I'm trying to rig eyes on my rig. They have two layers on with the eye whites and one with the pupil.[image: Two Layered Eye] When I try to move it, it can go into the skin of the character and look like it's floating.[image: Floating Eye Skin]When I rotate it, it can also sink back into the eye white its self.[image: Eye Sink]If anyone could help me fix this problem and get normal looking eyes it would be greatly appreciated. I should also include I'm using Blender version 2.79b

Comment: if the white and the pupil are parented to the same bone it should not happen, perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Use a *UV_Warp* modifier to move a pupil texture on a single mesh. You can drive the modifier with bones. UV offsetting is also supported in most game engines, it's the best setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you're going to want the pupil and white connected on the same surface. having them disconnected can only lead to strange shadows and collisions like this. The best way to set up eyes so that there are no strange collisions like this is to make a sphere for the eyes. once you have the sphere you place the 3D cursor in the center of it (key stroke : shift+S > U aka cursor to selection) then select your eye bone and put the Head in the cursor at the center of the eyes (Shift+S > T) and then put the tail in the center of the pupil. Now the eye will rotate from the center of the sphere and therefore the pupil will stay flush against the surface of the sphere no matter what direction you rotate it.